# some values of sine function

Tags: trigonometry

how to show that

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{10} = \frac{\sqrt5 - 1}{4}$$
$$\sin \frac{\pi}{60} =  \dfrac{\sqrt{30} + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{20 + 4 \sqrt5} - \sqrt6 - \sqrt2 - \sqrt{60 + 12 \sqrt5}}{16}\,\!$$
$$\sin \frac{7\pi}{15} =\frac{\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt5} + \sqrt{15} + \sqrt3}{8}$$

I know that $\sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\cos \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ because of [image]

but what about the other values ??? how to find them using analytic way or geometric way ?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438362/evaluate-cos-18-circ-without-using-the-calculator/438413#438413) for $\sin (\pi/10)$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf) for $\sin (\pi/60)$ (and other values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled "*Sine of 36*" and I found [this webpage](http://www.intmath.com/blog/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles/6212). It supplies explanations and links to pages with other explanations for a whole host of angles.