# Determine if the number $ \sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} $ is rational

Tags: arithmetic, irrational-numbers, radicals

$ \sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} $

I have tried to raising it to the square, but I can't obtain the result.

$ \sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}= k $

$ 2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}} -2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}} = k^2  $

$2(\sqrt{(10+2\sqrt{5})(10-2\sqrt{5}})=2\sqrt{80}=8\sqrt{5}=k^2$

Is this a good lead?

@EDIT one more thing, how to show that $ \sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} + \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} $ equals to $\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow all the steps, but the conclusion appears to be correct : If this number is rational, then you can conclude that $\sqrt{5}$ is rational, which it is not.

Comment: Using this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438362/evaluate-cos-18-circ-without-using-the-calculator),

$$8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}=8(1+\cos18^\circ)=16\cos^29^\circ$$

Comment: Two out of your three steps are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, your steps aren't quite valid; if you have a statement of the form
$$
\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} = c
$$

Then, while it's true that 
$$
\left(\sqrt a - \sqrt b\right)^2 = c^2
$$

this unfortunately doesn't simplify to
$$
a - b = c^2
$$

rather, you get
$$
a - 2\sqrt a\sqrt b + b = c^2
$$

(check this by "foil"-ing).

What *is* true however, is that

$$
(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = a - b
$$
(again, check by "foil"-ing), and that $\sqrt a - \sqrt b$ is rational if and only if $\sqrt a + \sqrt b$ is (and so, as a consequence of this assumption, $a - b$ would be rational as well).

So

$$\left(\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\left(\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}} + \sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\\
= 8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}} - (8-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}})\\
= 4\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$$

*Now*, you might try squaring things.

Comment: I understand your method but I don't know what to do next. I know that $a-b$ isn't rational but I'm looking for $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$

Comment: Continuing with Baron's solution

$$4\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}\in\Bbb Q\implies \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}=\frac pq\in\Bbb Q\implies$$

$$10+2\sqrt5=\frac{p^2}{q^2}\in\Bbb Q\implies\sqrt5\in\Bbb Q$$

Comment: ok, now I see, thank you